# Docker-compose. Error response from daemon: mount denied: the source path too many colons

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose

I'm using Docker for Windows with Linux containers.
My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    web.facade:
        image: auth_webfacade
        ports:
        - "5236:80"
        build: ../
```

I'm trying to `docker-compose up` but I'm getting an error:

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                  docker:default
[+] Running 0/0
 - Container docker-web.facade-1  Creating                                                                         0.0s
Error response from daemon: mount denied:
the source path "\\Users\\User1\\AppData\\Roaming/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\\Users\\ContainerUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\UserSecrets:ro"
too many colons
```

I tried to `docker-compose create` but got the same error.
However, I can create and run a container with default settings using Docker Desktop.

Comment: Since it's complaining about a mount, I'm surprised you don't define any `volumes` in your docker-compose file.

Comment: @HansKilian Thank you! This helped me identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in the file `docker-compose.override.yml` which was created automatically after  `Add > Container Orchestrator Support` to solution using Visual Studio 22 following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2022).

As commentator hinted, the reason was `volumes` written in this file.

[screenshot VS22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atTG0.png)

My `docker-compose.override.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web.facade:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```